# Knowledge Base about Windows Defender

Tags: windows, antivirus

I am trying to find more information on the alerts that come up from Windows Defender and include one of the following:

- Remediation Status: What is it?, what are all the different types? and what each of them means?
- Action Status: What is it?, what are all the different types? and what each of them means?

Comment: You mean, like this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-remediation-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: I'm thinking that your answer will likely be found in Defender's documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I could not find anything in this link unfortunately. The Defender documentation is something publicly available?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, SCCM server is configured to work with Wndows Defender. Everytime something occurs we get an email that has the following 2 entries: -Remediation Status and Action Status. I understand what Remediation Status is about although I don't have information about the different types it supports. Also I don't understand what Action Status is about.

Comment: I Googled SCCM Defender and got: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90fd30c4-83e6-4122-a08c-1408518f32fb/why-remediation-action-quotnoactionquot-on-detecting-malware-with-windows-defenders-periodic?forum=win10itprosecurity

Comment: This is looking like a Windows product documentation question. It looks like more of an SCCM interface to Defender question. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/protect/deploy-use/monitor-endpoint-protection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it appears to not just be a Defender source, but an SCCM source of knowledge you need.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/protect/deploy-use/monitor-endpoint-protection

> **Malware Alert Levels** Use the following table to identify the different Endpoint Protection alert levels that might be displayed in
> reports, or in the Configuration Manager console.
>
> **Alert level**
>
> **Failed** Endpoint Protection failed to remediate
> the malware. Check your logs for details of the error.
>
> Note: For a list of Configuration Manager and Endpoint Protection log
> files, see the "Endpoint Protection" section in the Log files in
> System Center Configuration Manager topic.
>
> **Removed**   Endpoint Protection successfully removed the malware.
>
> **Quarantined**   Endpoint Protection
> moved the malware to a secure location and prevented it from running
> until you remove it or allow it to run.
>
> **Cleaned**   The malware was
> cleaned from the infected file.
>
> **Allowed**    An administrative user
> selected to allow the software that contains the malware to run.
>
> **No Action** Endpoint Protection took no action on the malware. This might
> occur if the computer is restarted after malware is detected and the
> malware is no longer detected; for instance, if a mapped network drive
> on which malware is detected is not reconnected when the computer
> restarts.
>
> **Blocked**   Endpoint Protection blocked the malware from
> running. This might occur if a process on the computer is found to
> contain malware.